# Requesting an iOS development certificate from Xcode 4.6.3 issue

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, provisioning-profile, iphone-developer-program

I requested a development certificate through Organizer > Devices > Library > Provisioning Profiles > Refresh button, and I got it approved by an admin user of my team, and I can see it in Member Center but I don't see it listed in Organizer nor I was asked if I wanted to export my developer profile as it is supposed happen as described in [App Distribution Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582).

Does this mean that something went wrong, or is it just due to the fact that I needed an admin approval to get the development certificate? Anyway, shouldn't it be listed in Organizer > Devices > Library?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From Organizer it is not going to work, until you don't have .p12 certificate for your system.  Make a .p12 certificate for your distribution profile where it is set by admin and then you can check with provisioning profiles.